Replacing a specific brand logo instead of that same brand text above product title
How to replace a specific brand logo instead of that same brand text before above product title as in the image attached here and I'm working on Wordpress Ecommerce website though with the mentioned link - https://spacearcade.in/
see highlighted
And I have tried the following code with action Hooks/Filters but still it didn't worked for me. So any help or solutions would be more appreciable alot.
Thanks in Advance :D
That code in functions.php :
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_template_single_title', 5);
function custom_template_single_title() {
    if(is_product_category( 'category-name' ))
    {
    global $product;
    echo '<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">'
         . '<img src="image.png">' 
         . $product->get_title() 
         . '</h1>';
}
    
}

Replacing a specific brand logo instead of that same brand text above product title.

Your code doesn't work certainly because of your theme own customizations… You need to contact the theme authors in their support pages.
